# OnKeyPress event do same stuff on multiple inputs

Tags: javascript

I have 3 inputs, when I press enter on them same operations happend.

**This is my code**

How would you do this better?

```
    var __this = this;
    var a = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("more-content")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var b = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("more-content")[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var b = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("more-content")[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

    a.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // do same stuff here
        }
    };
    b.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // do same stuff here
        }
    };
    b.onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // do same stuff here
        }
    };
```

Comment: It'd be better if you also add corresponding HTML code.

Comment: [See this code](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p3cu14b6/)

Comment: @Tushar, i like your example, unfortunately i can paste the html, there are other inputs that don't need the same behavior

Comment: @insertusernamehere , yes i can

Comment: no there are no other inputs where something else happens. just other inputs with nothing to happen on keypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact different ways to handle your request. Here's one I'd like to show as it is:

- re-useable <sup>(As you can use it on any element everywhere on the page multiple times.)</sup>
- decoupled from the HTML markup and from CSS classes

**HTML**

Add a `data-*`-attribute to the fields where the magic should happen:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="a" data-log>
```

**JavaScript**

- query those specific elements
- attach the event handler to each element
- run your code

*The ES5 way:*

```
var logMe = document.querySelectorAll('[data-log]');

for (var i = 0, max = logMe.length; i < max; i++) {
    logMe[i].addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (13 == event.which) {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://jsfiddle.net/0fzm8x2r/)

*The ES6 way:*

```
let logMe = document.querySelectorAll('[data-log]');

for (let item of logMe) {
    item.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (13 == event.which) {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://jsfiddle.net/56ybdatv/)

---

That being said, you can alternatively use CSS classes as well to identify the elements:

```
<input class="log" type="text" name="a" value="a">
```

And select the elements using:

```
let logMe = document.getElementsByClassName('log');
```